# Youtube api v3 list ordered playlist items

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to order videos from a playlist using PlaylistItems:list? For example, when using the API to fetch related videos to a video using Search:list, you can order the videos returned by date, rating, relevance, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs entry for PlaylistItems:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) doesn't show such a feature, so I would say it's impossible to do it directly.

You could achieve this manually, though, by fetching all the videos' data and writing an algorithm that orders them.

Comment: I should probably add this as a feature request in that case over at youtube's api issue tracker.

Comment: Would definitely be useful!